# Create a fixed cell size grid that automatically scales

Tags: html, css, gridview, datagrid, inventory-management

I would like to create an inventory view in my website. Basically it should look like this:

[image]

Note that the width of the grid (in multiples of elements) always adjust to the screen size of the device. Also the grid container should always automatically fit to the width of the chosen grid width.
I have tried to do this using css-grid, although I could not figure out how to have css-grid automatically determine the number of columns based on screen size.

Then I tried to simply set a fixed size for every image and just let HTML natural page break take care of it:
[image]

This does in fact work, but on the left hand size you can clearly see that the grid container margin is larger than on the right, because the browser doesn't adjust the container according to the optimal column number.
Heres the code on how I did it (made it in react, but that doesn't really matter for this problem):

```
  render() {
    const gridCSS = {
        display:"block",
    }

    var x=Array.from(Array(99).keys())
    return (
        <div style={gridCSS}>
        
        
            {x.map((a)=> (
                    <img src="//placekitten.com/80/80" style={{border:" 2pt inset #0ff"}}/>
                )
            )
            }
        
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Is there a better way to create an inventory view with fixed size elmenets than this? And if there isn't, how can I adjust the grid container to always fit to the nearest multiple of elements?

Answer (score 2):

You need `display: grid`, which offers the problem to your solution.

I have added `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 80px)`, because of this it creates columns with the width of 80px, depending on the width of viewport. The repeat function's second argument cannot be `1fr`! If you specify it as `1fr` or any other fr values it won't work. You can use rem, %, em, etc. here instead of px. But you cannot use fr units here, because it won't give you desired result.

`grid-auto-rows: 80px` this property makes sure that, whenever a new is created for the grid it's height will always be 80px. So no matter how many rows are generated automatically by the browser their height will always be 80px.
`grid-gap: 10px`, this property makes sure we are keeping a `10px` of gap between each grid-item.

THen comes the main property that makes the grid items span right at the center of the grid, `justify-content: center`. This property align the whole grid on the horizontal axis.

```css
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 80px);
    grid-auto-rows: 80px;
    grid-gap: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
    <div class="grid-item"><img src="//placekitten.com/80/80"/></div>
</div>
```

Here's the working example of the css-grid:
https://codepen.io/prathameshkoshti/pen/XWKOGeM

Comment: thanks a lot, this already almost perfect. But is there a way to ensure that the grid container always adjusts its width and height to its content? For example in your codepen, make it so the grid div always has a 10 px margin at left, right, top and bottom?

Comment: Yes it does have the capability by using `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(80px, 1fr))` and `grid-auto-rows: auto` (this auto row is default behaviour), but the first property uses the 1fr as max-width which means grid item will always take up available free space if available else will stay at least 80 px wide, but because of this the grid will take up whole space and the margin (not really margin) will be uneven on the left and right side of the grid.

Comment: Grid gap is not the margin, but you can say that they are gutter between the grid-items which will appear only between grid-items, but not around the grid-items. You can use others values as well like rem, px, %, etc